# Reading dates from file to linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, scanf, fgets

```
void readDataFromFile(President **h) {
    FILE *fp = fopen("President.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot open a file!\n");
        return;
    }

    char buffer[MAX];
    int rno, start_date, end_date;
    char name[MAX];

    while(fgets(buffer, MAX, fp) != NULL) {
        // Reading data from line
        if (sscanf(buffer, "%d %[^\n] %d-%d", &rno, name, &start_date, &end_date) != 4) {
            printf("Error trying to read file!\n");
            fclose(fp);
            return;
        }

        // Creating of new node
        President *newNode = (President*)malloc(sizeof(President));
        if (newNode == NULL) {
            printf("Memory error!\n");
            fclose(fp);
            return;
        }
        newNode->rno = rno;
        strcpy(newNode->name, name);
        newNode->start_date = start_date;
        newNode->end_date = end_date;
        newNode->next = NULL;

        // Adding new node to list
        if (*h == NULL) {
            *h = newNode;
        } else {
            President* current = *h;
            while (current->next != NULL) {
                current = current->next;
            }
            current->next = newNode;
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);
    printf("Data is added to list!\n");
}
```

Hello. I'm trying to read from file to linked list , but i always get an error cause of if(sscanf). What is wrong with my code? I've checked several time the text inside the file but its ok , but anyway cant read it.Can i have some help or maybe some useful links? I'm ready to manage it by myself if you show where i can read about it.

Here are three sample lines from the input file

```
1 President 2000-2004 
2 President 1932-1957 
3 President 2012-2016
```

Comment: Diagnosing a problem with reading from a file would be much easier knowing what was in the file.

Comment: "%[^\n]" will allow sscanf() to read all characters until you reach '\n' (newline marks end of line).   I think that consumes the rest of the line, leaving nothing for  start_date  and end_date.  If sscanf() is returning exactly 2, then that might be a tell that this is the problem.

Comment: Please post three lines from the file. If the items are all space-separated you'll need to do some analysis, to determine whether the name has one, two, or more spaces in it.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: ...with program comments and responses in English, please.

Comment: In the question please. Edit the question to show lines that demonstrate all the variants in the file.

Comment: 1 President 2000-2004
2 President 1932-1957
3 President 2012-2016 

in such format. Its all not in one line, dont know how to type like in file here

Comment: `Cannot open a file` is the canonical example of a useless error message.  Try: `const char *name = "President.txt";  if( (fp = fopen(name, "r")) == NULL ) { perror(name); ...`  This does three things: the error message goes to stderr, it includes the name used to access the file, and it provides a reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My testing of your code reveals that the regular expression %[^\n] consumes the rest of the line, leaving nothing for variables start_date and end_date, and is very likely root cause of the issue.

I suggest this regular expression: %[^ ]  -- which will stop scanning at the first white space:

```
sscanf(buffer, "%d %[^ ] %d-%d", &rno, name, &start_date, &end_date)
```

If there are 2 names separated by space, you might do this to address that scenario -- please keep in mind that successful sscanf() should return 5 in this example:

```
sscanf(buffer, "%d %[^ ] %[^ ] %d-%d", &rno, fname, lname, &start_date, &end_date)
```

NOTE: @Weather Vane very kindly pointed out that %s will work in place of %[^ ].  Yes, of course!  (Thanks again).

All suggestions tested successfully on data file having this format... showing version 2 (first name + last name):

```
1 First Last 1933-1944
2 First Last 1944-1948
...
...
```

Comment: 1 President 2004-2016    - this is data that contains in file.

Comment: @Poizone  -- good, thank you.  Then the 1st example (above) should work nicely for  you ...and sscanf() should return 4.

Comment: @Poizone then why to you need `%[]` and not `%s` for the name?

Comment: @Weather Vane  ha!-- good call.    %s will do nicely by itself in the ideal scenario.

Comment: @Kz2023  Thanks. There is no error now but can't write to linked list. Nothing happens. Might be something wrong with nodes. I will try to figure it out.

Comment: @Poizone  -- Here is my complete [test bed](https://godbolt.org/z/Gx3bs6rsE).  Please consider using this or similar for testing the file read and scan by itself before adding on.  I often have to create functions alone like this to fully test them before adding to a larger project.  It actually saves time in the long run.

Comment: @Kz2023 `==` has higher precedence than `=`... Might want to correct your `if()` as it's currently not doing what you think it's doing...

Comment: @Fe2O3  -- thanks! I appreciate you.   I got hasty... I knew I should have parenthesized that.  I didn't know that about = vs ==       .... thx again

Comment: @Kz2023 I make the same mistake too many times, so I try to be aware of it... Study up on _precedence of operators_. It's useful knowledge. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Given the format of the input lines, `sscanf` cannot parse them in a single call as posted. You should use `strchr()` and `strrchr()` to locate the first and last space characters, then use `sscanf()` to convert the numbers and `strcpy` to copy the middle part, the name, which may have multiple spaces embedded, eg: `Theodore Roosevelt`, `William H. Taft`.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void readDataFromFile(President **h) {
    FILE *fp = fopen("President.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open file %s: %s\n",
                "President.txt", strerror(errno));
        return;
    }

    char buffer[MAX];
    int rno, start_date, end_date, count = 0;

    // Locating the last node if any
    while (*h != NULL) {
        h = &(*h)->next;
    }

    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, fp) != NULL) {
        char *first = strchr(buffer, ' ');
        char *last = strrchr(buffer, ' ');
        if (!first || !last
        ||  (first += strspn(first, " ")) >= last 
        ||  sscanf(buffer, "%d", &rno) != 1
        ||  sscanf(last, "%d-%d", &start_date, &end_date) != 2) {
            fprintf(stderr, "invalid format: %s\n", buffer);
            break;
        }
        while (last > buffer && last[-1] == ' ')
            last--;

        // Creating of new node
        President *newNode = calloc(sizeof(*newNode), 1);
        if (newNode == NULL) {
            fprintf(sdterr, "Memory allocation error!\n");
            break;
        }
        newNode->rno = rno;
        // copy the name: use `snprintf` to prevent buffer overflow
        snprintf(newNode->name, sizeof newNode->name,
                 "%.*s", (int)(last - first), first);
        newNode->start_date = start_date;
        newNode->end_date = end_date;
        newNode->next = NULL;

        // Appending new node to list
        *h = newNode;
        h = &(*h)->next;
        count++;
    }

    fclose(fp);
    printf("%d records added to list!\n", count);
}
```